Fishing coax through two floors
I’m trying to run coax from my attic to my second floor. I got it from the attic to a wall cavity in the third floor no problem, and can access the bottom of the wall cavity (at floor level) through an access hatch for the bottom of the bathtub. I’ve drilled half-inch holes in similar but not identical (within 3 inches) positions in the studs going between the second and third floor wall cavities and the area between the floors (~15 inches between the studs), but I have limited room to maneuver. Using fishing wire and (cheap) fish sticks with magnetic tips, I can’t seem to get the coaxial through. What do you suggest?

I know what you mean, but what my mind sees is fish sticks

fishing wire is to soft and will bend to easily

A metal coat hanger often works for me.

I'm not sure I fully understand the geometry of your situation but fashioning a hook out of metal wire, you can pull a cable around laterally inside a stud bay. If you tape some twine to the end of the cable you can even get the twine thru the hole with it, and use that to pull the cable.

Are you trying to tun the coax directly, or run pull string to use to pull the coax?

You drilled down from the top and up from the bottom, and your'e 100% certain the two holes are in the same joist bay?
Some ideas:

Use a longer drill from below and go all the way through.   There are fishing drills that have a little hole near the end to tie a string once you get through.  There are drill extension rods.
You say "within three inches".  If you know that, why not drill again more accurately?
A good way to get a fishing wire to jog a few inches over through a half-inch hole is to buy a cheap plastic hoola hoop and stick it into the hole so its curve curves towards the destination.  Shove it in from the top in the right orientation and as much as necessary to be directly over the lower hole, then drop your line through.
A cheap borescope can help a lot with this.  Buy one with a dual camera and with its own screen (no phone needed).

